# Split a dataset into two new dataset based on percentage of split

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to split by large dataset randomly into two new dataset in the ratio of 70% - 30%.

Basically I need to allocate 70% of random values from large dataset to the newdataset1 and 30% of the random values from largedataset to the newdataset2.

Can you please help with a SAS code that will help me achieve it.

A dummy code will really help..

Proc SQl or SAS statement. Anything will work with me.

Comment: What approach have you tried yet? Please tell us first.

Comment: Look at `proc surveyselect` online and see how that can help you.  If you get stuck then post another question with what you have tried

Comment: Thanks Keith, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

For complex sample design (like stratified randomization, e. g.) `PROC SURVEYSELECT` is a way to go, as @Keith said.
But for just a simple random splitting `RANTBL`-function will do the trick:

```
  data newdataset1 newdataset2;
    set have;
    flag=rantbl(-1, 0.7, 0.3);
    if flag=1 then output newdataset1;
    else output newdataset2;
  run;
```